# $X.A.A^{-1}=P.A.A^{-1}\\X=P$, right?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be a non-zero vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $P$ be a point in $n$-space. What is the dimension of the set of solutions of the equation:
>
> $X.A=P.A$

I guess the dimension is n, once $X.A.A^{-1}=P.A.A^{-1}\\X=P$

Assuming $A$ is invertible.

**Questions**:

Is my answer right?

Comment: $A$ is a vector. It doesn't have an inverse.

Comment: Only a square matrix can have an inverse, so $A^{-1}$ does not make sense. Can you show that the solutions are vectors such that $X-P$ is orthogonal to $A$?

Comment: What is an invertible non-zero vector? Normally $A$ means a matrix, not a vector.

Answer (score 2):

If $\vec x$, $\vec p$ and $\vec a$ are vectors than what has sense is to search $\vec x$ such that $$\vec x\cdot \vec a= \vec p \cdot \vec a$$.

Using the properties of the dot product this becomes:
$$
\vec x\cdot \vec a- \vec p \cdot \vec a=0\quad \iff \quad (\vec x-\vec p)\cdot \vec a= 0
$$
and this means that $(\vec x-\vec p)$ must be orthogonal to $\vec a$.

Comment: What is the dimension of the space of solutions?

Comment: It depends on the dimension of the vector space. In 3-D space it is the plane orthogonal to the vector $\vec a$ passing through $\vec p$.